# Can the ったら form of a verb be used to mean "after?"

Tags: verbs, conjugations

Take this example:

AったらB

Could this mean, "After doing A, B happened?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if B is in the past tense. This adds a flavor of surprise at the results to the sentence.

> 「食事できた」といったら、ぼくらが食べなかった！

Source: [Tae Kim](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals)

Comment: 「『食事できた』と言ったら、ぼくらが食べなかった。」 sounds unnatural and makes no sense, I'm afraid. I can't find that example sentence on the linked page. Did you make it up yourself? What did you try to mean by that?